# What happens when two nodes attempt to write at the same time in 2PC?

Tags: software-design, distributed-system

Does anyone know what happens when two nodes try to write data at the same time and both initiate the 2PC protocol? Does a request from one node get aborted and another one succeed? The failed node would retry with some exponential backoff?

If not, what happens?

Answer (score 0):

Usually resource managers does not allow both nodes to participate in the same transaction in the same transaction branch at the same time. Probably second node/binary/thread which tries to join to the transaction will get timeout or some other error on xa_start(..., TMJOIN) call.